# Access External Link router-link button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wanting to pass an external URL to be accessed by a button in my application. However, I want to access this URL globally, but I'm not able to implement it. When running my implementation nothing works

global.js

```
export const baseAppUrl = 'http://localhost:8080'
```

Component.vue

```
<script>
import { baseAppUrl } from '@/global'
export default {
  name: "app-header",
  data: function () {
    return {
      baseAppUrl: baseAppUrl,
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>

<b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" :to="baseAppUrl">SINGUP</b-button>
```

Comment: Can you give more details of what you mean by "nothing works"? b-button is a BootstrapVue component. How was it imported into the project? How is the b-button rendered in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `baseAppUrl` in the global file seems to be loaded correctly.
The problem is another one: the button should be wrapped in the `template` tag like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>This is the base app URL: {{ baseAppUrl }}</p>

        <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" :to="baseAppUrl">SINGUP</b-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { baseAppUrl } from '@/global'
export default {
  name: "app-header",
  data: function () {
    return {
      baseAppUrl: baseAppUrl,
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>
```

Plus make sure that the file `global.js` is placed in the right directory.